# what is the error in my first test code of VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
port ( SW     : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
       LEDR  : out std_logic
     );
end test;

-- architecture of the logic
architecture behavioral of test
begin

   my_test : process (SW) 
    begin
          if    (SW = "00") then
                     LEDR(0) <= '1';
              elsif (SW = "01") then
                     LEDR(0) <= '0';
              elsif (SW = "10") then
                     LEDR(0) <= '0';

              else
              -- hold                    
          end if;
    end process my_test;

end behavioral;
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my sample test code. I am using a DE1 board for testing
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your Question has very little information and thus it might get closed. Please be sure to stick to our guide [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, I would recommend you [edit] your question and include (1) what you expect to happen  (2) What happens instead (e.g. error message)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have declared LEDR as `std_logic`, a single bit variable, but you probably wanted to declare it as a vector eg:`std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);`. I am guessing this, because you  refer to LEDR as a vector later on - in your process the command `LEDR(0)` refers to the first position in that vector.
2. You have not created any conditions in your else statement. I am not sure what are you willing to achieve with your code, so it is difficult to tell what should be here...

Answer (score 0):

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
port ( SW     : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
       LEDR0  : out std_logic
     );
end test;

-- architecture of the logic
architecture behavioral of test is
begin

my_test : process (SW) 
    begin
          if    (SW = "00") then
                     LEDR0 <= '1';
              elsif (SW = "01") then
                     LEDR(0) <= '0';
              elsif (SW = "10") then
                     LEDR0 <= '0';

```
          else
          -- hold                    
      end if;
end process my_test;
```

end behavioral;